# trying to build R-package 'rimage' under windows

Tags: r, fftw

The package `rimage` is abandoned, but I was hoping to build from the old source specifically to be able to read Aviris image data files.  So first off, if anyone knows of an `R` package over at github or somewhere with this capability, that'll meet my needs.

The problem I'm running into in trying to build `rimage` (via cygwin, with `Rtools` installed on my machine) appears to be that the modern versions of `fftw` library don't match the versions called out in the `configure` and related files in the `rimage` source.  The errors I get after calling `./configure` are

> ```
> checking fftw.h usability... no
> checking fftw.h presence... no
> checking for fftw.h... no
> configure: error: Sorry, can't find fftw header
> ```

I have installed the latest fftw3 libraries pretty much anywhere (Rtools library directory, cygwin lib directory) that seemed sensible, but if there's a specific place they should have been placed, please let me know that as well.
thanks for all help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to import AVIRIS ENVI files, have a look at `hyperSpec::read.ENVI`. It does not (yet?) provide specific support for the .spec files nor for any georeferencing (as I mainly work with micro-spectroscopy), but adding the wavelength information is reasonably easy by hand:

```
require ("hyperSpec")

cuprite <- read.ENVI (      file = "data/cuprite/f970619t01p02_r02_sc01.a.rfl",
                      headerfile = "data/cuprite/f970619t01p02_r02_sc01.a.hdr")
spec <- read.table (        file = "data/cuprite/f970619t01p02_r02.a.spc")

colnames (spec) <- c ("wl", "refl", "V3", "V4", "i")
spec <- spec [order (spec$i),]
wl (cuprite) <- spec$wl
labels (cuprite, ".wavelength") <- expression (lamba / nm)

plotmap (cuprite [,, 827], col.regions = alois.palette ()) # slow
```

`hyperSpec` works with the data cube unfolded into a data matrix with accompanying `$x` and `$y` information. While this is flexible, you'll probably want to set up an indexing matrix to quickly retrieve images. Or you can reshape the matrix `cuprite$spc` to get the hypercube in an array.

Comment: Thanks - I'll play with`hypeSpec` to see how that goes.  As it happened, I found `caTools::read.ENVI` which seems to do a pretty good job.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: `caTools::read.ENVI` was the starting point for developing `hyperSpec`'s ENVI import filters. I don't remember exactly why I decided to derive my own version but probably it was that I needed some fine-tuning in order to adapt the code to variants I encounter from files exported from various (micro)spectrometer manufacturers (Varian/Agilent, Nicolet).